# Swiftmailer: Problems with sending mails using CLI

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I use Symfony and SwiftMailer as post manager. I can send post using console command, but when I send using browser client the post is not sent and there is nothing in log files. What can be the reason of such strange behavior?

Comment: The title says you have problems sending mails using CLI and the post says the contrary... Please clarify this and add more details in your question. It's hard to help you if we know nothing about your project.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but consider that SwiftMailer actually sends all the mails at the end of request processing, so don't interrupt your code with `die` or `exit` or they will never be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLI  - Command Line Interface 
CGI - Common Gateway Interface

You probably mean CGI php that deals with browser routine.

I faced the same problem using nginx. Swiftmailer refuse  to send any e-mails triggered by CGI PHP, but nevertheless it successfully sends e-mails by swiftmailer:email:send command in console.

I found that the cause of this problem is function stream_socket_client in disabled_functions of my nginx config. Just remove stream_socket_client from disabled functions, reboot your server and try again, it should help.